# .content div:nth-child(1):hover .content div:nth-child(2) не применяется

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="content">
    <div><img src="image/sheep.png" alt="">534</div>
    <div><h3>Palma de Maltorca</h3>
        <span>Spain</span></div>
</div>

.content:hover .content div:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;  
}
```

Не применяется свойство, помогите плиз.
Нужно что бы при наведении на блок "content" второй блок в блоке "content" исчезал. В блоке "content" два DIVa у обоих position: absolute; и они не занимают все место в блоке.

Comment: Попробуйте объяснить словами, что Вы хотите сделайте. Пока Вам минус.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался:

```
.content:hover > div:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте классы, что бы уменьшить число ошибок.

```css
.content__image:hover + .content__title {
    display: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="content__image"><img src="image/sheep.png" alt="">534</div>
    <div class="content__title"><h3>Palma de Maltorca</h3>
        <span>Spain</span></div>
</div>
```